# Differences between Google Play Installed Apps "UPDATES" list vs "MANUAL UPDATES" list?

Tags: android, google-play

When I launch Google Play on the phone and I enter the "My Apps" section, I can see all my installed apps spread into three lists:

- Updates
- Manual Updates
- Up To Date

I published my app to Google Play and whenever I launch a new version, my app appears in the *Manual Updates* list. I want my app to appear in the *Updates* list and not *Manual Updates*.

How can I achieve that? What is the difference between *Updates* and *Manual Updates* on that list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your app will appear in the *Updates* list unless you change the permissions that you're requesting. If you add, say, the `CAMERA` permission at some point, then your app will appear in the *Manual Updates* list until your user accepts the new permission.